# spring data oracle - non-numeric character was found

Tags: sql, oracle, spring-data

I have the table `disponibility` with this columns.

[image]

I created the below query

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select count(*) from disponibility d WHERE d.fk_room = ?1 "
        + "AND ((d.starthour < ?2 AND ?2 < d.endhour) OR (d.starthour < ?3 AND ?3 < d.endhour)) "
        + "AND ((d.startdate < TO_DATE(?4, 'dd/MM/yyyy') AND TO_DATE(?4, 'dd/MM/yyyy') < d.enddate) OR (d.startdate < TO_DATE(?5, 'dd/MM/yyyy') AND TO_DATE(?5, 'dd/MM/yyyy') < d.enddate))")
int checkUnicityRoom(String roomId, int startHour, int endHour, Date startDate, Date endDate);
```

return this error

> ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You entered a **date** value which isn't really a date. See the demonstration:

This is OK:

```
SQL> select to_date('15/02/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy') today from dual;

TODAY
----------------
15.02.2021 00:00
```

But this isn't (note `ab` in the place of the month):

```
SQL> select to_date('15/ab/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy') today from dual;
select to_date('15/ab/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy') today from dual
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected


SQL>
```

I don't know which values you used, but - check what you're passing to the `TO_DATE` function.

---

As you commented that value you use is `Wed Apr 11 01:00:00 CET 2018`, it is obviously different from `dd/MM/yyyy` format mask you used along with the `TO_DATE` function. These two **must match**.

In your case:

```
SQL> select to_timestamp_tz('Wed Apr 11 01:00:00 CET 2018', 'Dy Mon dd hh24:mi:ss TZR yyyy') datum
  2  from dual;

DATUM
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
11.04.18 01:00:00,000000000 CET

SQL>
```

As table column's datatype is `DATE` you should

```
SQL> select cast(to_timestamp_tz('Wed Apr 11 01:00:00 CET 2018', 'Dy Mon dd hh24:mi:ss TZR yyyy') as date) datum
  2  from dual;

DATUM
----------------
11.04.2018 01:00

SQL>
```

Comment: the date used is like this `Wed Apr 11 01:00:00 CET 2018`

Comment: Right; value and format mask don't match, while they should. I added some more info into the answer; have a look, please.